# SSO Logout on JBoss 7.1.1 is not working for all webapps

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, single-sign-on

I have different webapps on a JBoss 7.1.1. All of them are configured to use the same security-domain and the whole JBoss is configured to use SSO.

Login works like expected. If I login to Webapp 1 and switch to Webapp 2 the SSO is working. But If I do a logout in Webapp 1 (request.logout()) I am still logged in in Webapp 2. Is there any way to do a logout on every webapp which is bound to the SSO? I have not found anythink in the documentation.

Here is my current configuration:

**standalone.xml**

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
    ...
    <sso reauthenticate="false"/>
</virtual-server>
```

**jboss-web.xml (similar in all webapps)**

```
 <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">java:/jaas/myDomain</security-domain>
  <valve>
     <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name>
  </valve>
```

If anyone knows a solution, it would be a huge help for me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of jboss 7.1.1. (Workaround present.)
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5728